# How to declare Typescript types for generated Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ajv

What's the right way to declare types for generated Javascript that allows it to be exposed from a library? It seems like it should be straightforward, but getting the hand-written `.d.ts` file to be used **and** copied to the `outDir` is proving very difficult. Currently, I'm getting the `.d.ts` files generated by `tsc` in the `outDir`, so it has inferred types instead of the correct ones.

Source structure:

```
src/
  __generated__/
    validateEvent.js     <-- generated
    validateEvent.d.ts   <-- NOT generated, but doesn't seem to work elsewhere
  Event.ts
  index.ts
```

`validateEvent.d.ts`:

```
import { ValidateFunction } from "ajv";
import { Event } from "../Event.js";

export const validate: ValidateFunction<Event>;
export default validate;
```

`index.ts`:

```
export * from "./Event.js";
export { default as validateEvent } from "./__generated__/validateEvent.js";
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "composite": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["es2021"],
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2022",
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

There seems to be two related questions here:

1. How can I get my `.d.ts` file copied to `outDir` instead of the one generated from the generated Javascript?
2. Can I put my `.d.ts` file somewhere other than the `__generated__` directory? (If I can solve this, maybe #1 is moot. I've tried various forms of `declare module`, but nothing has worked except putting the `.d.ts` next to the generated source.)

If it matters, I'm using ES modules and `tsc --build` with project references. As a temporary hack, I am manually copying the `.d.ts` files to `outDir`, but that doesn't play so well with `tsc --build --watch` and `nodemon`.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer so far is just to import the generated Javascript with generated typings and then export a casted version:

`index.ts`:

```
export * from "./Event.js";

import { ValidateFunction } from "ajv";
import { Event } from "./Event.js";
import { default as validateEvent0 } from "./__generated__/validateEvent.js";

export const validateEvent =
  validateEvent0 as ValidateFunction<Event>;
```